# Invalid character(?) being prefixed to the data record into database column when inserting XML data

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am seeing a strange behavior in the data that is being inserted into the database. In the table say "table1" when I am inserting a record, for which one of the columns contains value as below:

```
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <OrderPayLoad xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<OrderID>182806333</OrderID> 
<CreatedDateTime>2011-11-27T22:59:37.56</CreatedDateTime> 
<MarketCode>XXX</MarketCode> 
<AccountNumber>0</AccountNumber> 
<MobileNumber>0</MobileNumber> 
<OrderTotal>0</OrderTotal> 
<OrderTaxTotal>0</OrderTaxTotal> 
<PaymentMethod>NCC</PaymentMethod> 
<ReceiptMethod>P</ReceiptMethod> 
<ShippingInfo>
<FreightTypeID>1</FreightTypeID> 
<ShippingAddressType>STANDARD</ShippingAddressType> 
</ShippingInfo>
<BillingInfo>
<BillToZip>-</BillToZip> 
</BillingInfo>
<OrderDetails /> 
<PaymentCard /> 
<OrderRoutingID>2</OrderRoutingID> 
</OrderPayLoad>
```

Until the point I reach `dbTransaction.Commit()` I saw the above XML data in the column. When I check the database and pull up the same record, I see an extra character getting prefixed to the XML.

Any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: It could be a byte order mark (BOM). Check your source XML for that before inserting the XML to the db. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem got fixed automatically, tried best to reproduce it. Not able to find the actual root cause.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed closing tag `</OrderPayLoad>`, so below is the correct xml, please use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<OrderPayLoad xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <OrderID>182806333</OrderID> 
    <CreatedDateTime>2011-11-27T22:59:37.56</CreatedDateTime> 
    <MarketCode>XXX</MarketCode> 
    <AccountNumber>0</AccountNumber> 
    <MobileNumber>0</MobileNumber> 
    <OrderTotal>0</OrderTotal> 
    <OrderTaxTotal>0</OrderTaxTotal> 
    <PaymentMethod>NCC</PaymentMethod> 
    <ReceiptMethod>P</ReceiptMethod> 
    <ShippingInfo>
        <FreightTypeID>1</FreightTypeID> 
        <ShippingAddressType>STANDARD</ShippingAddressType> 
    </ShippingInfo>
    <BillingInfo>
        <BillToZip></BillToZip> 
    </BillingInfo>
    <OrderDetails /> 
    <PaymentCard /> 
    <OrderRoutingID>2</OrderRoutingID>
</OrderPayLoad>
```

Comment: I have inserted the raw XML data from database. If you see "?" character is at the start of the XML

Comment: Would you please update me the data type of your inserting column, thanks for your times.

Comment: Your xml is not valid in format, it is safe to insert appropriate xml into your table, however if your used column data type is not xml then it should insert without any error, if you're still getting error in that case use `N` before your xml like `N<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>.... `, hope this would be helpful, thanks for your time.

Comment: command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayLoad", _payLoad.Trim()));
The above line is used when I try to insert from code behind.

Below is the type declaration in Stored procedure
 ,@PayLoad text

Comment: I cant modify the code as it has hundreds of dependencies. Why is "?" being automatically prefixed to the text column. Do you know why is it being inserted?

Comment: There no specific reason for what "?" is being prefixed automatically, however I've another suggestion to you that is: add data type to you parameter as: `SqlParameter PayLoad = new SqlParameter("@PayLoad", SqlDbType.Text);
            PayLoad.Value = _payLoad.Trim();
            command.Parameters.Add(PayLoad);`, hope this would be helpful, would you please try with this, thanks for your time.

Comment: I used the code you provided, it is still prefixing the "?" character to the raw data.

Comment: My I have your code block, so that I can debug and can assume why it is happening, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of your SQL column? The prefix char could be a the "BOM" (Byte-order-marker) used by UTF-8. If your column is text, char or varchar instead of ntext, nchar or nvarchar this could cause the extra symbol in front of your data.

Comment: command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayLoad", _payLoad.Trim())); 
The above line is used when I try to insert from code behind. 

-- Below is the type declaration in Stored procedure ,@PayLoad text

Comment: @MubashirKoul try changing "text" into "ntext"